# I want my Ubuntu server 18.04 to shutdown every night at a certain time? How can I do this?

Tags: shutdown

Hello I just setup a ubuntu server running samba and I want it to shut down every night at 11PM.

[This is what's in my crontab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G7Yy.jpg) I'm using this command in crontab `30 9    * * *   root   shutdown -h now`

[Cron tab does seem to be on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBT5.jpg) but its not running the command at the desired time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to use cron, check out my link...

Comment: @Ravexina Your duplicate is better! :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? "It doesn't work" doesn't help a bit in the diagnosis of the issue at hand. What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

Edit the system crontab:

```
sudo vi /etc/crontab
```

Add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
0   23   *   *   *    root     shutdown -h now
```

Save the file (ZZ in vi).
That should run the command "shutdown -h now" every night at 23:00.

Comment: I tried that now but it doesn't work?

Comment: I used this code '0   23   *   *   *   *    root     shutdown -h now' and it doesn't shutdown when it becomes that time.

Comment: I think there should be one less *.  Also, perhaps "root" isn't required.  Maybe something like this:  0 23 * * * shutdown -h now .  Type "man 5 crontab" to see the format.

Comment: There are 5 time columns: min, hour, day-of-month, month, day-of week.  So Ray is right, it should be  "0 23 * * *   root     shutdown -h now".   "root" is needed in /etc/crontab to specify the user running the command.  In the user's crontab, no 'user' column is present.  I have edited the answer to reflect Ray's correction.

Comment: @Paperboypaddy maybe you are missing a newline character at the end of file? According to man, it will cause to cron demon consider the file broken.